# Why don't processes split by fork() proceed through this function identically?

Tags: c++, c

I am confused by the fork() function in C/C++.
Given the following code:

```
void fork2()
{
    printf("LO\n");
    fork()
    printf("L1\n");
    fork();
    printf("Bye!\n");
}
```

Lecture slides give the following diagram

```
         ______Bye
   ___L1|______Bye
  |      ______Bye
L0|___L1|______Bye
```

To me, this diagram doesn't make any sense. I expect that each call to fork will result in a  call to `printf("LO\n")`. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Why would something done BEFORE the fork occurs be run in both processes?

Comment: Your assertion about each call to fork calling `printf("LO\n")` is incorrect. In order to say where you went wrong you have to explain first what makes you think that each call to `fork` will call `printf("LO\n")`. Where did you get that idea from?

Comment: The way I was thinking, it creates brand new process, and starts from the beginning of the process. But apparently, I am totally wrong.

Comment: It creates a brand new process, which starts from **the point where the `fork()` call is made**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

fork() creates an exact duplicate of the process that made the fork() function call.  This means, that you then have two processes that are exactly the same, and are at the same point in the program.  If we step through the fork2() function, the following happens.

Process A (original process):
L0   (process A forks, creating process B)
L1   (process A forks again, creating process C)
Bye! (process A exits)

Process B:
L1   (process B forks, creating process D)
Bye! (process B exits)

Process C:
Bye! (process C exits)

Process D:
Bye! (process D exits)

It is up to the operating system as to which process it proceeds with at each fork, and also as to whether it switches to another process at any point during run-time, so the output can be interleaved at any point after a process forks.  For example, if the OS chose to always follow the new process until the end of the function, you would get the following output:

```
L0   (A)  
L1   (B)  
Bye! (D)  
Bye! (B)  
L1   (A)  
Bye! (C)  
Bye! (A)
```

Answer (score 15):

You are wrong.  When forking, both the parent and child process continue from the same place - *after* the call to `fork()`, not at the start of the function.  It's easy to verify this behaviour - change your function's name to `main()` and then compile and run it:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("LO\n");
    fork();
    printf("L1\n");
    fork();
    printf("Bye!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
LO
L1
Bye!
L1
Bye!
Bye!
Bye!
```

There's nothing like actually trying something to figure out how it works...

Comment: A +1 because you were faster. ;)

Comment: Thanks @BKevelham - I sent one your way too. =)

Comment: Nice answer. Also note that the OS scheduler might cause the printing order to be other than what you expect because of context switching.

Comment: +1 @liorda.  There are no guarantees about how the output will turn out.

Comment: Thanks, not it makes more sense !

Answer (score 7):

You're wrong. :) After the fork both processes will execute the next instruction following the fork.

Answer (score 5):

The behavior of `fork()` requires some getting used to, because it actually *forks* the execution path into the parent and child processes (it returns `0` in the child process and the PID of the child process in the parent process).

It means that after the first call to `fork()`, you'll have two processes running the same code, and after the second call you'll have *four* processes (because both processes issued the `fork()` call), still running the same code. Thus, the graph:

```
     L0
    /   \
   /     \
  L1      L1
 /  \    /  \
Bye Bye Bye Bye
```

Answer (score 0):

BTW, fork() is not a C/C++ library function. It's a library function to call a Unix system call. There are plenty of C/C++ implementations that do not have fork().